# Find the cumulative distribution function, F(x)

Tags: probability, integration

Consider a continuous random variable X with Probability Density Function $f(x)=\dfrac{c}{(x+1)^4}$ for $x\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise.

I found $c$ to be 3 after anti-deriving $f(x)$.

Now I need to find the cumulative distribution function, $F(x)$.

Is it just $$\int_0^{
\infty}\dfrac{3}{(x+4)^4}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

It would just be the integral:
$$F(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{3}{(t+1)^4}dt$$
This may be evaluated with the substitution $u=t+1$.

Comment: Why are the bounds from 0 to x? This is the part that confuses me

Comment: What's the probability that $X$ is in the interval $(-\infty,x]$?

Answer (score 1):

The Cumulative Distribution, $F(x)$, is defined as 
$$F(x)=P(X\leq x)$$
and if you have pdf $f(x)$ this can be found by 
$$P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dx$$